# Timeseries chart in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

**To do:**
Plot time series line chart using the library, where x-axis time-stamps are not equidistant.

**Sample Data:**

1467886121:  325
1467886153:  326
1467886185:  325
1467886248:  326
1467886280:  326
1467886311:  326
1467886343:  327
1467886375:  327
1467886406:  327
1467886438:  328
1467886529:  328
1467886561:  327
1467886593:  327
1467886625:  326
1467886659:  327
1467886692:  326
1467886725:  326

**Note:**
LHS values are UNIX timestamps and RHS values are data points at corresponding timestamps.
The timestamps aren't equidistant and so they should be spaced according to the time difference between the two. Recently, MPAndroidChart introduced this functionality [github: [link]](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/LineChartTime.java)

Over here they seem to be adding new values separated by one hour. I want to add values according to the timegap in UNIX timestamps.

How do I go about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TR4Android's answer is absolutely fine except for the fact the library doesn't support long datatype for the timestamps.

So, I have gone with the following approach:

**Sample Data:**
1467886121: 325,
1467886153: 326,
1467886185: 325,
1467886248: 326

Taking **timestamp_1** to be **zero** or the **base**.
The following timestamps become base timestamp(first timestamp) - itself.

So, the data now becomes like so,

**Processed Sample Data:**
0: 325,
32: 326,
64: 325,
127: 326

This data can now be passed on to the charting library and the drawn graph has its time-series nature preserved.

Comment: This doesn't really work as you are making the assumption that the time will be incrementally more in the next timestamp. The difference in time between the next step could be less than your last step and the graph would plot backwards.

Comment: Well, no. The graph will work correctly. I just assume the first timestamp to be zero, then the future timestamps become the difference. So, we maintain the time series nature as well. Its first minus nth timestamp which results in smaller nature preserved timestamps. I have edited the answer for clarity. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Time series are supported in the latest version of the library, at the time of writing this would be `v3.0.0-beta1`. Make sure you import that version in your `build.gradle` file.

It is pretty straightforward to construct your entries, as each entry now consists of a x-value and a corresponding y-value, just like your data (how you retrieve your x- and y-values depends on how your input data is structured):

```
ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    long x = ... // 1467886121, 1467886153, ...
    int y = ...  // 325, 326, ...
    entries.add(new Entry(x, y));
}
LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, "Time series");
LineData data = new LineData(dataSet);
mLineChart.setData(data);
```

Since you are creating a time series, you'll probably also want to format the axis labels to be dates, you can find the sample's [`DayAxisValueFormatter` on GitHub](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/custom/DayAxisValueFormatter.java). You'll need to adjust this to fit your needs and then add it to your x-axis:

```
mLineChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new DayAxisValueFormatter(mLineChart));
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, and it does seem to work - for some reason, the actual dates are off by 2 years, and enabling this feature slows down the app to freaking molasses!

Comment: Did you simply copy the provided sample formatter? You'll need to actually adjust it, the `int determineYear(int days)` method calculates the year based on 2016 which might explain the difference. Don't know about the performance...

Comment: Sure, I noticed that caveat too. As for the performance, the issue seems to stem right from how this date-formatting approach works - the speed-up solutions require changing my data, which I'd rather not. Generally, this approach comes with some serious compromises. I've chosen to use another lib for my time-series data.